Book in which a girl dies on a railway track and her sister brings her back in a virtual world
This is on behalf of my daughter who read the book a few years ago. How she described it to me:
In the book, the girl is electrocuted on a train track - electricity travels through a balloon she is carrying.
The girl was working on a virtual world or some kind of VR tech.
Her sister later carried on / discovered this VR world and was able to bring back or perhaps find her sister (or a digital recreation of her) inside this world.

Somebody else on another forum thought they may have read this book but couldn't remember the title. They provided this additional info, which may help:

the girl previously told her sister that she wanted to be a video
game developer when she grows up, which was a lie because she was
embarrassed of her aspirations
the sister was chasing the girl on the railroad when she got
electrocuted
the sister felt guilty for the situation so she gave up on her dreams
and become a game developer and built the reality to allow her to
talk to her sister
the reality is broken and it is constantly fading away

